# Хранение файлов в базе vs хранение в файловой системе

Tags: sql, windows, sql-server, файлы, файловая-система

Хотелось бы увидеть + и - различных видов хранения, и когда какой лучше использовать.

С файловыми таблицами, я не работал, но я предполагаю, что там меньше головной боли с файловыми операциями, например файл не может быть блокироваться процессом, наверное есть транзакции(Т.е нельзя убить файл, если вдруг при добавлении его в таблицу, клиент отвалится). Поправьте если я не прав.

UPD:
Enttity Framework дружит с файловыми таблицами?

Comment: А вы тут на SO в поиске не вводили "файлы в базе", подобные вопросы примерно раз в месяц проходят ...

Comment: И собственно что такое "файловая таблица" ? А большинство написанных вами предположений неверно. 1. Процесс может блокировать файл. 2. нет транзакций.  3. как писать файл и игнорировать при этом отваливание клиента или нет решать вам. Если машина неожиданно перезагрузится или произойдет другой сбой недописанный файл может остаться на диске

Answer (score 13, accepted):

В SqlServer вы можете использовать следующие варианты (некоторые из них применимы и к другим СУБД).

**Вариант 1**

В БД хранится "заголовок" файла (например, путь к файлу плюс, возможно, какой-то набор атрибутов):

```
create table [TableName]
(
    ...
    FilePath nvarchar(4000) not NULL,
    ...
)
```

а данные хранятся отдельно в файловой системе. Размер БД меньше, чем если хранить в БД также и данные. Но нужно следить за ситуациями "файл есть, заголовка нет" или "заголовок есть, файла нет". На мой взгляд, если файлы являются логически важной частью данных БД (не кэш, не какие-то временные данные), то лучше посмотреть на другие варианты.

**Вариант 2**

В БД хранится также и содержимое файла (в столбце типа `varbinary(max)`).

```
create table [TableName]
(
    ...
    FileData varbinary(max) FILESTREAM not NULL,
    --либо
    --FileData varbinary(max) not NULL,
    ...
)
```

Здесь две опции - с `FILESTREAM` и без.

Без `FILESTREAM`:

- данные хранятся в БД (в т.н. LOB pages)
- размер данных одного элемента ограничен 2Gb

С `FILESTREAM`:

- данные хранятся в файловой системе (именно как файлы)
- нет ограничения в 2Gb на элемент
- данные `FILESTREAM` не участвуют при подсчёте лимита на макс. размер
  БД (к чему чувствительны Express Edition)
- к данным можно получить доступ через соотв. API со стороны файловой
  системы
- (SqlServer 2014 и далее) запрашиваемые данные не отъедают из buffer
  pool, оставляя больше памяти для обработки запросов

И с `FILESTREAM` и без поддерживаются транзакции. С `FILESTREAM` при доступе через Transact-SQL поддержка полная, при доступе через файловую систему есть ограничения (смотреть [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173763.aspx)).

**Вариант 3**

Использование таблиц специального типа [FileTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff929144.aspx).

```
create table [FileTableName]
    as filetable
```

Их функционал основан на использовании `FILESTREAM`. Таблица представляет иерархию хранящихся файлов/директорий, их данные и атрибуты. В варианте 2, чтобы создать/удалить файл, нужно создать/удалить соотв. запись в таблице. В данном варианте это можно делать напрямую через файловую систему. Например зайти в соответствующую директорию (SqlServer создаёт для этого соответствующую UNC share), создать какой-то файл/директорию, удалить/изменить, потом сделать запрос `select * from FileTableName` и увидеть соответствующие изменения. И наоборот - при вставке записи в таблицу через SQL в директории появится соответствующий файл или директория.

Какой вариант когда лучше использовать - думаю, зависит от конкретной задачи. В [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb895234.aspx) более детальное описание и сравнение вариантов 2 и 3.