# Хранение файлов в базе данных

Tags: c#, sql-server

На данный момент у меня в программе реализована возможность обмена сообщениями между студентами и преподавателями, где я просто использую заголовок, дату, имя отправителя и само сообщение. Хотел бы попробовать добавить возможность перетаскивать файлы в поле для написания сообщения и тем самым отправлять их вместе с текстом. Поскольку сообщения хранятся в базе данных, следовательно, сами файлы так же придется хранить в ней, однако я не знаю, возможно ли это в принципе и если да, то как это стоит делать)

Comment: Лучше хранить файлы отдельно от базы в некоем каталоге, а в базе хранить адреса на эти файлы. Потому что хоть технически это в некоторых базах возможно, но обычно совершенно не рентабельно. База будет сильно пухнуть, вставлять/извлекать долго и вообще работать не удобно. [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/527843/%d0%a5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b5-vs-%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5?rq=1)

Comment: SQL Server может легко хранить XML или JSON.

Comment: @PavelPopov при filestream пухнуть не будет.

Comment: смотря какая БД, в MS SQL можно например хранить в таблице в формате varbinary